# s3 bucket access to ec2 instance using iam role

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to access the s3 object from node js SDK using instance IAM role but it's not working getting `status: 403` its permission denied. I am able to access bucket using awscli.

Is there anything in DSK where I have to mention about we are using IAM role instead of the access key and secret key?

Comment: Are you saying that you can access the bucket via the AWS CLI from the same instance that is running that code? Do you have any hard-coded credentials in your code or in a settings file that might be overriding the credentials from the Instance Metadata assigned by the IAM Role? The code is either making a different API call or using different credentials.

Comment: Yes, awscli is working on the same server.  i haven't provided keys using any method. the code is making https://buckername.s3.amazonaws.com/ calls and proxy to a client request.

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, there is nothing more we can offer. Either the node app is making calls that are different to your CLI calls, or it is using different credentials from somewhere. You could experiment by making the bucket or object temporarily public to show that the node app is successfully accessing the bucket/object, just to prove that your code is working.